# Creating a "shared zlib context" in .net core

Tags: c#, websocket, discord, compression, zlib

I'm trying to build a WebSocket client for the Discord API as a fun side project, but I've run into an issue that I can't seem to resolve currently.

https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway#encoding-and-compression

In their example for how to decompress input data returned from their API, they say:

> Transport Compression: Currently the only available transport
> compression option is zlib-stream. You will need to run all received
> packets through a shared zlib context, as seen in the example below.
> Every connection to the gateway should use its own unique zlib
> context.

My first time decompressing a response from them (as in for one connection) works as expected, but the second time gives me an error saying "unknown compression method".

I'm assuming that this is because some portion of what I'm instantiating to decompress the first response needs to persist for future responses for this connection (just going off what their documentation says), but I'm not sure what that actually means in C# for what I'm using.

```
static byte[] Decompress(byte[] data)
{
    using var compressedStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(data);
    using var zipStream = new ZlibStream(compressedStream, CompressionMode.Decompress);
    using var resultStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
    zipStream.CopyTo(resultStream);
    return resultStream.ToArray();
}
```

Here is the method I'm using for decompression, ZlibStream comes from [Ionic.Zlib](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Ionic.Zlib.Core/), however using their built-in method: "ZlibStream.UncompressString", which seems to do the same thing, also produces the same error.

What exactly would it mean to "run all received packets through a shared zlib context" in this situation?
Is there some higher order compression context that I need to persist across all decompression tasks for a given connection? Something else?

Thanks in advance, let me know if I can clarify or add any additional details!

Comment: You should not use the name `zipStream` for the object. The zip file format is entirely different from the zlib stream format, and might confuse a reader of your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Mark Adler said, you need to feed the inflator packets in the right order. This is so that it has reference to the previous bytes and can use them to fill in the gaps.

I've managed to solve this using `Ionic.Zlib.ZlibCodec` which gives you more control over the codec (so that it doesn't keep starting a new context every time you inflate).

```cs
public class ZlibStreamContext
{
    private ZlibCodec _inflator;

    public ZlibStreamContext(bool expectRFC1950Header = false)
    {
        _inflator = new ZlibCodec();
        _inflator.InitializeInflate(expectRFC1950Header);
    }

    public byte[] InflateByteArray(byte[] deflatedBytes)
    {
        _inflator.InputBuffer = deflatedBytes;
        _inflator.AvailableBytesIn = deflatedBytes.Length;
        // account for a lot of possible size inflation (could be much larger than 4x)
        _inflator.OutputBuffer = new byte[deflatedBytes.Length * 4]; 
        _inflator.AvailableBytesOut = _inflator.OutputBuffer.Length;
        _inflator.NextIn = 0;
        _inflator.NextOut = 0;

        _inflator.Inflate(FlushType.Sync);
        return _inflator.OutputBuffer[0.._inflator.NextOut];
    }
}
```

I chop off the unused bytes in the buffer at the end there, but you don't need to if you're just going to use `System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byteArray)`. It will work even without properly sizing the output array.

Note: You need to chop off the header from the first packet discord sends you. Or you can set `expectRFC1950Header` to `true` and add the default header `78 9c` to each of the packets (though I'd recommend the former).

Answer (score 1):

It means that for a single connection, you need to keep the zlib decompression object open for that whole connection and keep feeding it packets, in order, until the connection is complete. Use the `Write` method on the decompression object for each packet.

At the same time the connection is complete, the zlib stream should also inform you that the data is complete, since the format is self terminating. Furthermore, there is a check value at the end that will report in an error if any of the data was corrupted.