# Unable to decompress in C# - what compression method is this message using?

Tags: c#, .net, compression, gzip, zlib

I have a base64 string `qsZhqyXY0rTEnOLUWgAAAAD//w==`.
This represents a UTF8 string in JSON format compressed using (I believe) zlib. I don't know the exact contents of the JSON.

I first convert this string to bytes:

```cs
var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64string);
foreach (var b in bytes) Console.Write($"{b:x2} ");
// aa c6 61 ab 25 d8 d2 b4 c4 9c e2 d4 5a 00 00 00 00 ff ff
```

This has the standard `00 00 ff ff` at the end, but none of the zlib magic headers I know:

- `78 01` low compression
- `78 9c` default compression
- `78 da` best compression

Typically, my understanding is that you are supposed to remove the first two bytes specifying the compression type when working with `DeflateStream`. Here is my method for decompressing this byte array, it removes the header, however even when not removing the header it fails.

```cs
public static byte[] InflateByteArray(byte[] bytes)
{
    var outputStream = new MemoryStream();
    MemoryStream inputStream = new MemoryStream(bytes, 2, bytes.Length - 2); 
    
    using var deflateStream = new DeflateStream(inputStream, CompressionMode.Decompress);
    deflateStream.CopyTo(outputStream); // exception here
    
    return outputStream.ToArray();
}
```

I get a `System.IO.InvalidDataException` with the message 'The archive entry was compressed using an unsupported compression method.' when I run this method on the above byte array.

Why is this happening? What compression method is this message using?

Comment: Do you know something about the data you try to extract? Should it be a text or something binary? Do you know the exact expected result?

Comment: @cly I have added this information the post

Comment: Did you try without skipping the first 2 bytes?

Comment: @Fildor Yes, there is a comment on the line before the input stream is created noting this, I will move it earlier for clarity.

Comment: @doliphin ah, missed it. Sorry

Comment: @Fildor Is it not required that there be a header though?

Comment: It doesn't look like a zlib compressed data. There are more possibilities than the three you noted but all start with 78. You may try to play around with the great [CyberChef tool](https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/) which can typically help with unknown data. I started a [recipe](https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/#recipe=From_Base64('A-Za-z0-9%2B/%3D',false)To_Hex('Space',0)&input=cXNaaHF5WFkwclRFbk9MVVdnQUFBQUQvL3c9PQ) for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a small piece of deflate data from the *middle* of a deflate stream. It does you no good without at least the deflate stream that precedes it. A deflate "disassembly" of it gives:

```
fixed
literal '{
match 23 118
literal '9
match 5 117
literal 'false}
end
stored
end
```

That `match 23 118` says to copy bytes from *way* before the data provided in this little deflate snippet. (117 bytes before.) Same for the second `match`. The decompressed data is a `{`, 23 bytes from the past you don't know, a `9`, five more bytes you don't know, and `false}`.

None of the these deflate blocks are marked as the last block, so there is more deflate data following this snippet.

The empty stored block at the end which you refer to as *"the standard `00 00 ff ff` at the end"* is not in fact standard. That is what is inserted when a deflate stream is broken up for some reason into small pieces for transmission, in order to bring each piece to a byte boundary. Normally deflate blocks can start at any bit location. You won't find those in a normally compressed deflate stream.

Comment: I've managed to guess as much from reading [one of your other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66089413/creating-a-shared-zlib-context-in-net-core) (you seem to pop up a lot on the [compression] tag). 
If I add a header to this data and decompress using DotNetZip's `ZlibStream` I get almost readable data with bits missing (which would be expected, it seems). How can I inflate in context of the previous message? Should I open a new question for this?

Comment: You have to start an inflator and keep it open, feeding it these snippets as you get them. In the proper order, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Try following :

```
           string input = "aa c6 61 ab 25 d8 d2 b4 c4 9c e2 d4 5a 00 00 00 00 ff ff";
            byte[] bytes = input.Split(new char[] { ' ' }).Select(x => byte.Parse(x, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber)).ToArray();
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes);
            ms.Position = 0;
            System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream gzip = new System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream(ms, System.IO.Compression.CompressionMode.Decompress);
            List<byte> uncompressed = new List<byte>();
            int bytesRead = 0;
            do
            {
                byte[] chunk = new byte[1000];
                bytesRead = gzip.Read(chunk, 0, 1000);
                uncompressed.AddRange(chunk.ToList().GetRange(0,bytesRead));
            } while (bytesRead == 1000);
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, sadly this does not work and throws the same exception.

Comment: I'm not getting error with posted code.  I'm getting 0x7B as first byte.  The uncompressed data has a string "false".

Comment: this is so odd, could you post what you get fully? What does your .csproj file look like? I don't really know how this could change much since deflate stream is supported by all frameworks. I'm using netcoreapp3.1, output type exe. I have no idea what else this could be.

Comment: I get the same error here [https://dotnetfiddle.net/Bthnty](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Bthnty)

Comment: I don't know if issue is with my version of Net or your version of Net.  Can you target a Net Version instead of Core..

Comment: I tried other versions, Net 4.5 works, but I get `{                       9     false}`. I might try use sharpziplib, as this seems to be rather buggy. Do you get this same thing or is yours more readable? Many thanks

Comment: That is what I got.  There are a lot of BREAKING changes with Core.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/3.1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228868/discussion-between-doliphin-and-jdweng).